# How to remove the text "Function" from \function?

Tags: algorithms

Im very new to latex and I want to write an algorithm like the picture below:

How can I write the Function of the algorithm like so?
I saw alternatives such as `\Procedure` or `\function` but they give me the words "Function" Or "Procedure" in front. How can I achieve the headers' results as below for my function wrapper?

Is there another tag for this?

[image]

Below is an example of the latex code im using

```
\begin{algorithm}
\caption{recursiveAlgo}
\begin{algorithmic}[1]
\Function{recursiveAlgo}{$mst, path, currentNode, drilled$}
\State stop <- false
\While{$!stop$}
\If{currentNode.childNumber != 0}{
    \For {$i=0$ to currentNode.childNumber - 1}
        \State      drilled ++
        \State      path.push\_back(currentNode.coord, currentNode.child[i].coord)
        \State      recursiveAlgo(path, currentNode.child[i])
    \EndFor}
\EndIf
\State \Return path;
\EndWhile
\EndFunction
\end{algorithmic}
\end{algorithm}
```

What I want to is to change the results of:

```
\Function{recursiveAlgo}{$mst, path, currentNode, drilled$}
```

Which appear as:

[image]

How do I show the function name without its type declared and the name in bold like the example in the first picture?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: @DG' Hi, Thank you for your suggestion, I've edited my question to include some MWE and clarify further what i want

Comment: You code is still not compilable, but it's a good start.

Comment: Please make your code compilable (if possible), or at least complete it with `\documentclass{...}`, the required `\usepackage`'s, `\begin{document}`, and `\end{document}`. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for TeX.SX users willing to give you a hand. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the manual, you can change the keywords:

> **3.1.10 Changing command names**
>
> One common thing for a pseudocode is to change the command names. Many
>   people use many diﬀerent kind of pseudocode command names. In
>   **algpseudocode** all keywords are declared as `\algorithmic<keyword>`.

If you want to change the keyword for `\Function` you have to declare:

`\algrenewcommand\algorithmicfunction{\textbf{whatever}}`

[image]

And you can leave it empty, of course:

`\algrenewcommand\algorithmicfunction{}`

[image]

Comment: Many thanks and thank you for your time!

Answer (score -1):

In `algpseudocode.sty` function was called like

```
\algdef{SE}[FUNCTION]{Function}{EndFunction}%
   [2]{\algorithmicfunction\ \textproc{#1}\ifthenelse{\equal{#2}{}}{}{(#2)}}%
   {\algorithmicend\ \algorithmicfunction}
```

Change to

```
\algdef{SE}[FUNCTION]{Function}{EndFunction}%
   [2]{\algorithmicfunction\ \textproc{}\ifthenelse{\equal{}{}}{}{()}}%
   {\algorithmicend\ \algorithmicfunction}
```

in your tex file at preamble

Comment: Hi, Thank you for your answer although it's having the opposite effect of what i need. The results im getting now is just the words "Function" in bold without the name.

To clarify, I hope to have just the name of the function shown in bold